# How can I use %TYPE with Oracle associative arrays?

Tags: arrays, oracle, types, associative-array

I have declared an associative array type in some Oracle package header like:

```
TYPE ParamArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4096) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(512);
```

In my package body I would like to iterate through the array without repeating the string sizes to avoid mismatches when updating the package header.

My try was:

```
PROCEDURE IterateArray( Params ParamArray )
AS
  v_ParamName ParamArray%TYPE;
BEGIN
  v_ParamName := Params.First;
  WHILE v_ParamName IS NOT NULL LOOP
    -- do something with the array entry
    v_ParamName := Params.Next(v_ParamName);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

But this didn't work on my Oracle 10g test server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define you own type to handle the `varchar2` and the use your type, with no need to repeat the size.
For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE testpck AS
    SUBTYPE myType IS VARCHAR2(4096);     /* a type for the values */
    SUBTYPE myIndexType is VARCHAR2(512); /* a type for the index  */
    TYPE ParamArray IS TABLE OF myType
        INDEX BY myIndexType;
    PROCEDURE IterateArray(Params ParamArray);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY testpck AS
    PROCEDURE IterateArray(Params ParamArray) AS
        v_ParamName     myType; 
        v_index         myIndexType;
    BEGIN
        v_index    := Params.FIRST;

        WHILE v_index IS NOT NULL
        LOOP
            -- do something with the array entry
            v_ParamName := Params(v_index);
            dbms_output.put_line('value of ' || v_index || ' is ' || v_ParamName);
            v_index     := Params.NEXT(v_index);             
        END LOOP;
    END;
END;
```

The call:

```
declare
    myArray         testpck.ParamArray;
    myValue         testpck.myType;
    myIndex         testpck.myIndexType;     
begin    
    myIndex := 'ONE';
    myValue := 'VALUE OF ONE';
    myArray(myIndex) := myValue;     
    --
    myIndex := 'TWO';
    myValue := 'VALUE OF TWO';
    myArray(myIndex) := myValue;
    --
    testpck.IterateArray(myArray);
end;
```

Comment: I can compile the example but shouldn't the ParamArray definition use `INDEX BY myType` instead of `TABLE OF myType`?